# How to make www and root both work with Facebook Share Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Share Dialog with my app. It will work when I link to the site listed under my developer account (e.g. www.site.com), but will not work for the root (e.g. site.com). The opposite applies when I list the root domain without the www. Is this possible to do or must I instead forward incoming root requests to www to make Facebook shares work?

Comment: If both are displaying the exact same content, then you should decide on one “main” domain and redirect there anyway - not only because of Facebook, but search engines & duplicate content, etc.

Comment: Ok, will do. thanks CBroe.